# Select All Fields From Only Latest Created Record of dataset in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a comments table, and I can't quite figure out this query. These comments will be under a particular data record in this application, which is what comment_number refers to. When a comment is created, it is assigned that records 'comment number'.. The comment number + date_added identify each particular comment. If a comment is updated/edited, instead of updating the record itself, it creates another entry in the table with the same comment_number and date_added, and creates a new date_modified. This is due to compliance issues. I have to be able to go back in that particular comment's history.

Here is the table description:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------- +---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| comment_number | varchar(64)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| comment        | varchar(2048) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_added     | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_modified  | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| is_deleted     | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date_deleted   | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+--------------- +---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So different comments will have the same comment number, but will have different 'date_added' fields. And a particular comment's different versions in history will have the same 'comment_number' and 'date_added' value, but different 'date_modified' fields.

So i need to pull all the fields of the latest modified versions of all comments. I have been playing around with MAX() functions, as well as GROUP BYs, but i have not been able to get the correct results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what if a comment has been added but has never been edited? date_modified = date_added, or date_modified = NULL ?

Comment: I was going to say something like SELECT DISTINCT comment_number, comment, date_added, date_modified, is_deleted, date_deleted FROM THIS_TABLE_NAME ORDER BY date_modified DESC, but @fthiella has a good point.

Comment: @fthiella - date_modified=date_added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most recent date_modified for every comment, you need a query like this:

```
SELECT
  comment_number,
  date_added,
  MAX(date_edited) AS max_date_edited
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  comment_number,
  date_added
```

to get the latest version of the comment, you then need to join the result of this query back:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM
  table_name c INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      comment_number,
      date_added,
      MAX(date_edited) AS max_date_edited
    FROM
      tablename
    GROUP BY
      comment_number,
      date_added
  ) m ON c.comment_number=m.comment_number
      AND c.date_edited = m.max_date_edited
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use ORDER BY date_modified in your query, and then set the LIMIT to 1. Decide whether you need ASC (low to high) or DESC (high to low) to get the desired field as the first result.